# Keeping a constant connection with the server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, network-programming

In iOS is it possible to keep a connection constantly open listening for a call from the server? (The Server has not been implemented yet, so flexibility is available there depending on the best solution)

The app still has to keep checking for calls coming from the server because the user is not making a `GET` request manually. So what class is used for keeping an open ear for a call that can be received from the server anytime… e.g. Skype/Viber. They are always there waiting and listening for when the data is sent for a call.. how do they do it?

Should I use `NSStream` to create the connection and use `NSTimer` to keep it alive at regular intervals?

Answer (score 1):

To have a constant connection with your server you need to implement VoIP functionality, no timers are needed.

[Look in Apple documentation for more info.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)